# Botframework v4: waterfall stepcontext result. How to simplify?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have this dialog that either number prompt the user or confirm prompt the user depending on a property. It then check the type of waterfall stepcontext result if it is decimal or bool. It is working as intented but i think it is overcomplicated and prone to error.

Is there a better way to do this? Here is the code:

```
public class LoanCalculator : WaterfallDialog
{
    public LoanCalculator(string dialogId, IEnumerable<WaterfallStep> steps = null)
        : base(dialogId, steps)
    {
        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            // check if the property has a price
            var userstate = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["BasicAccessors"] as BasicAccessors).BasicUserStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);

            // if zero, decimal prompt
            if (userstate.PropertyPrice == 0)
            {
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                "numberPromptDecimal",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Indicate price of property."),
                    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter a valid amount."),
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // if not zero bool prompt confirm if user wants to change its value or not
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                "confirmPrompt",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Property price is {userstate.PropertyPrice}. Is this correct?"),
                });
            }
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var userstate = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["BasicAccessors"] as BasicAccessors).BasicUserStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);

            // if decimal prompt
            if (stepContext.Result is decimal)
            {
                stepContext.Values["price"] = Convert.ToDecimal(stepContext.Result);
                return await stepContext.NextAsync();
            }
            // if bool prompt
            else if (stepContext.Result is bool)
            {
                // if user does not want to change value
                if ((bool)stepContext.Result)
                {
                    stepContext.Values["price"] = userstate.PropertyPrice;
                    return await stepContext.NextAsync();
                }
                // if user want to change value, make value zero and restart dialog
                else
                {
                    userstate.PropertyPrice = 0;
                    return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // i dont know what to do with this so i just restart dialog
                return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(Id);
            }
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            // if stepcontext values is not equals to null
            if (!stepContext.Values["price"].Equals(null))
            {
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                "numberPromptDecimal",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Indicate amount of loan."),
                    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter a valid amount."),
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // again dont know what to odo with this
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"oops"));
                return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(Id);
            }
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            // continue
        });
    }

    public static string Id = "loanCalculator";

    public static LoanCalculator Instance { get; } = new LoanCalculator(Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [branching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow) into two possible sub-dialogs. Rather than accessing `stepContext.Values["price"]`, these sub-dialogs could return the price to the top-level dialog by passing it through `EndDialogAsync`.

**The rest of my answer nitpicks things about your code that you're not specifically asking about.**

Since you're asking for recommendations, I should mention that the Bot Framework samples seldom if ever extend `WaterfallDialog`. If you want to make your own dialog class it's more standard to inherit from `ComponentDialog` and then have a `WaterfallDialog` as its starting component, but in your case I'm not sure you need a custom dialog class at all. And if you do extend `WaterfallDialog` it's a bit strange to have the same two parameters in your constructor since you're surely not expecting to have any steps passed into it. Why not just do this?

```
public LoanCalculator() : base(Id, null)
```

Comment: I actually learn this type of coding on youtube since there is not so many tutorial on botframework v4. Is it better to use component dialog? All of my dialog are waterfalldialog like that. Can you elaborate more on the passing of values in the EndDialogAsync sir? Sorry i am still a beginner programmer. I am willing to learn how to better code this botframework.

Comment: If possible sir can you do an example of a more standard type of coding? Like this with a ComponentDialog and branch it out and also teach how to pass values in the end dialog along the way? I could refactor all my codes based on that example.

Comment: Did you look at the document I liked you to? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow

Comment: I can't see in there where is the component dialog but okay sir i will try to model my chatbot like in that document. thank you